# Modify prop value before TypeScript check

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

This is the object I've got:

```
const translations = {
    msg_hello: 'Hello',
    msg_bye: 'Bye'
}
```

Also I have a function that looks like this:

```
const generateTranslation = (partialKey: string): keyof typeof translations {
    return `msg_${partialKey}`;
}
```

is there a way to check if the generated translation key will be valid? For example:

```
generateTranslation('hello'); // good
generateTranslation('no'); // bad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need extract allowed values from `translations`. In order to do that, you need to make `translations` immutable.

```js
const translations = {
    msg_hello: 'Hello',
    msg_bye: 'Bye'
} as const;
```

Then, for the sake of readability, you can create helper type:

```js
type Translations = typeof translations;
```

Thanks to [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), you can infer the string which goes after underscore `_`:

```js
type GetSuffix<T> = keyof T extends `msg_${infer Suffix}` ? Suffix : never;

type Test = GetSuffix<Translations> // "hello" | "bye"
```

Now, you can apply the restiction:

```js
const generateTranslation = <
    Key extends GetSuffix<Translations>
>(partialKey: Key): `msg_${Key}` => `msg_${partialKey}`
```

Be aware that I have infered `partialKey` with help of `GetSuffix<Translations>` which helped me to apply explicit return type `msg_${Key}`.

WHole example:

```js
const translations = {
    msg_hello: 'Hello',
    msg_bye: 'Bye'
} as const;

type Translations = typeof translations;

type GetSuffix<T> = keyof T extends `msg_${infer Suffix}` ? Suffix : never

type Test = GetSuffix<Translations> // "hello" | "bye"

const generateTranslation = <
    Key extends GetSuffix<Translations>
>(partialKey: Key): `msg_${Key}` => `msg_${partialKey}`

const result = generateTranslation('hello'); // good --->  "msg_hello"
generateTranslation('no'); // bad
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCW4IwLwwG8BYAKBnJgFsIBzAfQAsBTFFEALhgHIAJFtrgBpSFKrToAjAJ5NOXAEIyupAL4xEOUJCgBuUqShSADkxgAVJKnRZIeOMaYgAZnEsQ0mbHpIGHMAOJMUADKAK5OThgAHgA8ZgB8dgDWTFLO5jBMUVBMYAAmOAAG1PQAJAQYYE5M8DBhEdEqhTAA-HXhkVEwnGBMAG41%20iSGJuZM0HaBIR3RcW4eNhCJAPTLMABEzKwg6zAAPhvSTOtDWhM0uTXoTBbI7tbgdjEiFADSqZnZuQUBQfWdczuC2w8VI8QAFEZEPBMIgUO8pJwEQBKTjFcTlBFNPCJdFlAhQmEYOFYwqnbCweDjUIoWD4C69JA5W5WTxgcFcLYCZE6GCrGA0EAgPIwAC04sSGxKjH4O1IDKuzPmD3ZXDAIC4PL5awkiDyQA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automatic way to do this, for dynamic strings like that where `keyof` won't retrieve them. But you could manually create a type that is a union of the valid values, and require that the `partialKey` argument be of that type:

```
const translations = {
    msg_hello: 'Hello',
    msg_bye: 'Bye'
};

type validPartialKeys = 'hello' | 'bye';

const generateTranslation = function (partialKey: validPartialKeys): keyof typeof translations {
    return `msg_${partialKey}`;
}

generateTranslation('hello'); // good
generateTranslation('no'); // bad
```